# How to append only once? jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

What I am trying to do is to append text to `.showError` only once every time you click on the button. Right now it appends each time you click on the button and get multiple times text appended to `.showError`. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
$("#send").on("click", function(ev) {
     $(".error-holder").empty();
     var err = 0;
     $("form .form-control").each(function(i, v) {
       if ($(this).val() == "") {
         err = 1;
       }
     });

     if (err == 1) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       $(".showError").append("Bij dit product moeten er serienummers ingevuld worden! <br /><br />");
       ($('#myModal').modal());

     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.html()`:

```
     $("#send").on("click", function(ev) {
$(".error-holder").empty();
var err = 0;
$("form .form-control").each(function (i,v) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        err = 1; 
    }
});

if(err == 1){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".showError").html("Bij dit product moeten er serienummers ingevuld worden! <br /><br />");
    ($('#myModal').modal());

}
```

Comment: Probably the best way, unless he has other error messages appended by previous code. +1

Comment: @Drakes Since the HTML Code is Not posted by OP, I thought .html() would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new variable before you start checking, let's call it

```
var showError=1;
```

Then go to your loop which checks for all the values and when you reach this stage

```
if(err == 1){
```

Edit it to like

```
if(err == 1){
  {
   if(showError== 1)
   {
         // Your append line here
         showError=0;
   }

    //Your Modal code here

  }
```

This way error will be shown only once because after that you are updating your variable to tell your if condition to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   var appended = 0;
     $("#send").on("click", function(ev) {
    $(".error-holder").empty();
    var err = 0;
    $("form .form-control").each(function (i,v) {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            err = 1; 
        }
    });

    if(err == 1){
        ev.preventDefault();
    if (appended == 0) {
        $(".showError").append("Bij dit product moeten er serienummers ingevuld worden! <br /><br />");
      appended = 1;}
        ($('#myModal').modal());

}
```